# Apache Cordova: Div gets blueish on Mouse Down

Tags: html, css, cordova, apache-cordova

I'm writing a little application with Apache-Cordova. I have two divs lookings like this (and the little yellow one):

[image]

As far everything is fine, but when I start adding click/mouse Eventhandlers to my green divs, they get blueish marked as far as I touch them (and the click doesn't trigger, when I am holding them too long).

```
<p id="GreenDiv" onclick="GreenDiv_OnClick()">
```

[image]

I've tried these in CSS so far, but this won't work:

```
-webkit-touch-callout: none;
-webkit-user-select: none;
-khtml-user-select: none; 
-moz-user-select: none;
-ms-user-select: none;
user-select: none;
```

Does anybody know how to turn that marking off?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer is this part of css I've found after much more googling:

```
-webkit-tap-highlight-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0);
```